# Adplus fullonfirst for a specific exception?

Tags: .net, debugging, adplus

A colleague is trying to track down a race condition, leading to an InvalidOperationException. I suggested adplus with fullonfirst, but it turns out that a third party library throws and catches all manner of exceptions under the hood. Is there any way if restricting to a managed exception type?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This old bugslayer post](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163530.aspx) describes how to configure Adplus to create mini dumps on specific exceptions.

Comment: Thanks, couldn't find that anywhere!